# What does `--rm` do when running a docker image with data volumes?

Tags: docker

While going through the docker documentation on running images with mounted volumes the following command has the `--rm` flag set on it.

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v ~/.bash_history:/.bash_history ubuntu /bin/bash
```

What does the `--rm` flag do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in the [docs](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/73ee139d7ae5bb1099744d3ac23eb70b418a4e6f/docs/reference/run.md#clean-up---rm):

> --rm=false: Automatically remove the container when it exits (incompatible with -d)

The container being run will be automatically removed it finishes its work. Volumes should stay untouched.

Comment: What influence does that have on the mounted volumes?

Comment: As far as I understood I should not affect mounted volumes.

Comment: This answer isn't describing the `docker run --rm` command ; instead it describes the `docker build --rm` command